# Python : Mobile code - migrate code between remote processes

Tags: python, real-time, distributed, auto-update

**Scenario**: An *AGENT* is running on multiple machines (A, B,C etc). AGENT = a Python process that acts as a hypervizor for Worker processes that run on a machine. Now the AGENT receives tasks, resolves them, starts/stops workers and keeps statistics.

I'm trying to find the best way of "teaching" the *AGENT* and the *Workers* new tricks. I'm trying to "send" over the network "mobile code" to all the *AGENTS* **without the need to restart** the *AGENT* process. This is NOT a remote procedure call issue. I need the code to be executed on the machine the AGENT is running.

I'm thinking of sending over the network ".py" files and make a custom "import".

Any pointers?! Has anyone tried to do this? I couldn't find any workable solution.

PS: I'm still using python 2.7 and please don't treat this as a question asked by a noob. I am quite proficient in Python and I do have an advanced understanding of programming in general.

I've experimented with [finder objects](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-finder) , read [PEP 302](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/).

I'm interested in a maintainable approach. Has anyone tried this?! What are the problems that may arise?!

Comment: Have you tried [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) (exists in python 2 as a statement)? - generally speaking remote code execution like you want it is potentially dangerous so make sure the code that is executed really is *your* code

Comment: I'm not trying to execute a function or two! I'm talking about shipping pure python modules and complicated code with a lot of new features.

Comment: If you are using the import mechanism your problem is [reloading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload) updated libraries. If you only have pure-python modules that do not import each other then exec-ing them with a new globals dict (then using the functions in there) is the simplest solution. If you need the import machinery then you should consider distributing your stuff as zips and [zipimport](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipimport.html) them

Comment: zipimport seems like a good ideea! This way I won't have to worry about folder structure.

Comment: I'm trying to use the most of what David Beazley presented at a PyCon [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oTh1CXRaQ0)